# How to fix "The Encapsulated Expression is Missing" error in JPA/Hibernate while using Update Named Query?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am getting excapsulated expression missing issue while writing named query.

```
int a = em.createQuery("UPDATE MyProsess d SET d.updateDate = current_date() WHERE d.personId = :personId")
```

[image]

Even when i pass multiple parameters to above query it gives some new errors. For example

```
int a = em.createQuery("UPDATE MyProsess d SET d.updateDate = current_date(), d.status=:stat WHERE d.personId = :personId")
```

[image]

Anyone could suggest how to resolve this issue?

Comment: You can not assign a Query object to int. You need to first execute for it to return the amount of records modified.

Comment: Are you calling executeUpdate at the end ?

Comment: Does your query have the following structure ?int updatedEntities = s.createQuery( hqlUpdate )
        .setString( "newName", newName )
        .setString( "oldName", oldName )
        .executeUpdate();

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it. Please replace current_date() with "current_date" remove the brackets I think HQL is not able to recognize it with brackets. Now in your Entities you have java.util.Date while current_date will return java.sql.Date this needs to be converted. Mark the attribute updateDate with @Temporal(TemporalType.Date) annotation to ensure smooth conversion.

Comment: No this current_date() is sql function. By removing it starts finding object or class with same name,

Comment: In JPA the function is used by current_date and this is translated to the platform dependent function. Remove the brackets. It will work test it.

Comment: Cannot convert to from java.sql.date to java.util.date: Type Mismatch

Comment: Change the type of updateDate of you Entities from java.util.Date to java.sql.Date and try again. You are working with SQL dates here they are not supposed to be java.util.Date

Comment: It is java.util.date in whole project and i am changing small part of it. So i could not touch classes or standards which already in there, i think i should drop idea of named query if this could not be achieve through it.

Comment: I understand can you try then to place the following annotation in your Entity @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) and try again with the current_date

Comment: This should ensure good conversion in between your java.util.Date and java.sql.Date